Windows Tiered Storage Space can't analyse or optimise
My PC has a Tiered Windows Storage setup that can't tier-optimise any more.
Tier optimisation has worked fine for many years but has recently started failing, with errors reported by both defrag and PowerShell cmdlets. Can anyone help me?
Error output
Using defrag:
PS D:\> defrag /c /h /g /#

Invoking tier optimization on Data (D:)...

        Tier Optimization:  skipped.

The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation. (0x8007139F)

Using PowerShell Optimize-Volume cmdlet:
PS D:\> Optimize-Volume -DriveLetter D -TierOptimize
Optimize-Volume : Failed
Activity ID: {862688a5-012a-0002-7b2b-3b862a01db01}
At line:1 char:1
+ Optimize-Volume -DriveLetter D -TierOptimize
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (StorageWMI:ROOT/Microsoft/...age/MSFT_Volume) [Optimize-Volume], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 4,Optimize-Volume

My configuration
Tiered Storage Pool with no resiliency, assigned as drive D, consisting of:

1x 1TB NVMe as the Performance tier
3x 4TB HDD as the Capacity tier (with parity redundancy)

Virtual disk:
FriendlyName ResiliencySettingName FaultDomainRedundancy OperationalStatus HealthStatus    Size FootprintOnPool StorageEfficiency
------------ --------------------- --------------------- ----------------- ------------    ---- --------------- -----------------
TieredSpace                                              OK                Healthy      6.74 TB         9.67 TB            69.67%

Storage tiers:
FriendlyName     TierClass   MediaType ResiliencySettingName FaultDomainRedundancy    Size FootprintOnPool StorageEfficiency
------------     ---------   --------- --------------------- ---------------------    ---- --------------- -----------------
HDD              Unknown     HDD       Parity                1                        0 B             0 B
NVMe             Unknown     SSD       Simple                0                        0 B             0 B
TieredSpace-HDD  Capacity    HDD       Parity                1                     5.86 TB         8.79 TB            66.67%
TieredSpace-NVMe Performance SSD       Simple                0                      900 GB          900 GB           100.00%

Physical disks:
Number FriendlyName    SerialNumber         MediaType CanPool OperationalStatus HealthStatus Usage            Size
------ ------------    ------------         --------- ------- ----------------- ------------ -----            ----
1      TOSHIBA HDWE140 [snipped]            HDD       False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select   3.64 TB
2      TOSHIBA HDWE140 [snipped]            HDD       False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select   3.64 TB
3      [snipped - not part of the storage array]
0      TOSHIBA HDWE150 [snipped]            HDD       False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select   4.55 TB
4      APS-SE20G-1T    [snipped]            SSD       False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 953.87 GB

Couple of things to ignore from the above:

I've removed disk 3 from this list, which is a dedicated drive C and not in the storage array.
Disk 0 is a slightly larger model, but the parity setup means its size is treated the same as the smaller two.
The allocated virtual disk space in the HDD tier is slightly below the physical capacity. Being honest I can't quite remember why, but I don't think it's relevant.

The PC is running Windows 11 Enterprise 23H2. The Windows Event Log is completely clean.
I set up the tiered storage using the PowerShell cmdlets around 4 years ago, shortly after installing a fresh Windows 11 build. I didn't use the Storage Spaces Control Panel to do it.
Could anyone suggest what I should try next? I've tried searching for information on the errors but they seem quite generic, so search results tend to be for unrelated problems.

This is still a problem, but interestingly I get no errors when running Optimize-StoragePool -FriendlyName "TieredSpace" if that's relevant.
